# DNS not resolved on Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop

Tags: networking, internet, dns, ethernet

Today, Ubuntu auto updated Gnome.

After restart, **I can not reach any website from Firefox, nor Chrome, either in ethernet or in wi-fi**.

DNS are not resolved anymore.

`resolvectl status`

```
Global
       Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
resolv.conf mode: stub

Link 2 (enp2s0)
Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 3 (enp62s0)
Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 4 (wlp3s0)
Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 5 (enx1eaba7d6e6c9)
Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 6 (ipv6leakintrf0)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: ::1
       DNS Servers: ::1
        DNS Domain: ~.

Link 7 (docker0)
Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
```

What should I do to fix this?

---

here is the result of a few commands, hoping someone could help.

`ip addr`

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 3c:07:54:0f:db:0c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.18/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp2s0
       valid_lft 83552sec preferred_lft 83552sec
    inet6 2a01:cb1d:8065:ff00:99b3:d756:827f:a773/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 86401sec preferred_lft 601sec
    inet6 2a01:cb1d:8065:ff00:d211:e869:1b78:4e94/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 86401sec preferred_lft 601sec
    inet6 fe80::c642:9766:63a5:aa4b/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp62s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 38:c9:86:32:b4:38 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e4:ce:8f:51:2a:14 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: enx1eaba7d6e6c9: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 1e:ab:a7:d6:e6:c9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: ipv6leakintrf0: <BROADCAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 22:af:bf:5d:77:7d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fdeb:446c:912d:8da::/64 scope global noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::3674:2c39:7a8e:a7e4/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:72:98:5e:fb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

`ip route`

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp2s0 proto dhcp metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp2s0 scope link metric 1000 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp2s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.18 metric 100
```

`ip neigh`

```
192.168.1.1 dev enp2s0 lladdr 30:7c:b2:8c:a0:56 STALE
192.168.1.15 dev enp2s0 lladdr a4:5e:60:ca:ff:09 STALE
fe80::327c:b2ff:fe8c:a056 dev enp2s0 lladdr 30:7c:b2:8c:a0:56 router REACHABLE
2a01:cb1d:8065:ff00:d886:7401:1e05:11ff dev enp2s0 lladdr a4:5e:60:ca:ff:09 STALE
```

`ping 8.8.8.8`

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=116 time=50.1 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=116 time=18.6 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=116 time=41.9 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=5 ttl=116 time=48.7 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=6 ttl=116 time=68.6 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=7 ttl=116 time=18.9 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=8 ttl=116 time=72.1 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=9 ttl=116 time=85.3 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=10 ttl=116 time=36.7 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 9 received, 10% packet loss, time 9026ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 18.589/48.995/85.270/21.767 ms
```

`dig google.com`

```
; <<>> DiG 9.18.1-1ubuntu1.1-Ubuntu <<>> google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

`ping 1.1.1.1`

```
PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.520 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.438 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.433 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.459 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.472 ms
^C
--- 1.1.1.1 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4073ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.433/0.464/0.520/0.031 ms
```

`dig google.com @1.1.1.1`

```
; <<>> DiG 9.18.1-1ubuntu1.1-Ubuntu <<>> google.com @1.1.1.1
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 45260
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.     24  IN  A   142.250.74.110

;; Query time: 19 msec
;; SERVER: 1.1.1.1#53(1.1.1.1) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Wed Aug 31 00:32:36 CEST 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 55
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error was mine. I removed Proton VPN, but forgot an instruction, which was still preventing the DNS resolution.

From the [Proton VPN docs](https://protonvpn.com/support/linux-ubuntu-vpn-setup/) :

---

**3. Disable Kill Switch if you have uninstalled the app**

The Kill Switch can be easily disabled from within the official Linux app, but this will not be possible if you uninstalled the app first without disabling the Kill Switch. This may result in your system being unable to access the internet. To remove the Kill Switch after the app has been uninstalled:

**a) Identify Proton VPN connection names by running the command:**

```
nmcli connection show --active
```

This will display a list of all your system’s active connections.

**b) Look for any connections with the pvpn- This usually includes pvpn-killswitch and pvpn-ipv6leak-protection, and may include pvpn-routed-killswitch. Delete all these connections using the following command:**

```
nmcli connection delete [connection name]
```

For example:

```
nmcli connection delete pvpn-killswitch
```

**c) Re-run the following command to verify that Proton VPN connections have been deleted:**

```
nmcli connection show --active
```

If any Proton VPN connections remain, delete them as described above.